# how to transfer jquery data between iframes

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe

So I have two iframes in page

```
<div id="ch">
    <iframe name="users" width="220" height="510" align="left" src='messages/users.php' id="userch" ></iframe>
    <iframe name="text"  width="450" height="405" src='messages/text.php'></iframe>
</div>
```

So I have variables in first iframe and I need to sent them into second iframe. I tried to use method GET. But any method that will work is good.

so first iframe

```
        <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta content="10; url=users.php" HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh>  
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <link href="../css/chat.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/ch_users.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body >
<div class="ess_contact">

<div>
    </body>

    </HTML>
```

2-nd iframe

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">  
<meta content="5; url=text.php?active=<?=$active;?>"  HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh> 
</head>
<body onload="scroll(0,100)" link="blue" alink="blue" vlink="blue">
<font size=3 face="Georgia">
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['active']))
    { 
        $active=$_GET['active'];
        echo $active;
        }
?>
</body>

</html>
```

and js file

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(document).on('click','.ess_contact', function () {

        var active = this.id;   
        $.get( "text.php", { active: active} );

});
});
```

Comment: all answers below (3) are correct, I can't choose exactly witch is the best but they are all work.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using PHP, you can start a session using `session_start()` and pass all your data through session variables.

Set:

```
$_SESSION['myvar']="the data";
```

Read:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['myvar'])){
   echo $_SESSION['myvar'];
}
```

Using the above, you can use GET or POST to transfer data across php pages. Unless you really have the restriction to use JQuery.

Comment: sorry the session will not work, for my situation because it is too much data that I planinng to transfer.  So can you provide variant with POST or GET method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried transferring data between iframes, and this is how I did it.

**Main.html**

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <h2>Iframe data test</h2><br/>
    <h2>Iframe 1</h2>
    <iframe src="f1.html" id="frame1"></iframe>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <h2>Iframe 2</h2>
    <iframe src="f2.html" id="frame2"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**f1.html**

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <h2>Iframe 1 here</h2><br/>
    <input type="text" id="mydata"/><br/>
    <input type="button" id="send" value="send data"/>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#send").click(function(){
        parent.$("#frame2").contents().find("#target").html($("#mydata").val());
    });
});

</script>
</html>
```

**f2.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Iframe 2 here</h2><br/>
    <div id="target"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You see the two iframes on the Main page. Type anything in the textbox and click *Send data*, the contents of the textbox will be set in a *div* found in the second iframe.

Comment: It is awesome... I want to see others ideas and methods... Especially the POST and GET method. But for now your answer is the best...

Answer (score 1):

Here i used AJAX. It's nearer to your code.
Here i created a jQuery.
This is the index.php file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
          <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
          <script src="t.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Below is iframe</h1>
        <iframe name="users" width="220" height="510" align="left" src='2.php' id="userch" ></iframe>
        <iframe name="text"  width="450" height="405" src='3.php' class="f3"></iframe>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is frame 1.  Name `2.php`;

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
          <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
          <script src="t.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello Milan from frame 2</h2>
        <h2>hello</h2>
        <h2>world!</h2>
                </body>
</html>
```

Here is frame 2. Name:`3.php`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
          <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
          <script src="t.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello Milan from frame 3</h2>
        <div class="msg"></div>
        <?php
        if(isset($_REQUEST['active']))
        {
            echo $_REQUEST['active'];
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is a jQuery named `t.js`.

```
function ifrm(){
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("h2").click(function (){
            var r=$(this).text();
            $.ajax({url:"3.php",data:{active:r},success: function (data) {

parent.$('.f3').contents().find('.msg').html(data);
                }});

        });
    });

}
ifrm();
```

Click on any text in `2.php` file and you can see what's going on in `3.php`.